# Heroku Postgres Database does not reflect schema changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a rails app on heroku. I recently updated the database by changing a column name and also adding a new column. Both the tasks were done using migration files. The changes were reflected properly on my local system. Also when I ran rake migration on heroku and restarted the app there was no problem. I can see the changes in the database schema by remotely connecting using pgadmin. But I cannot use the columns that are modified. When I edit my code to use the new columns application says that there are no such columns.

Thanks